# Setup many jdbcRealm on payara server

Tags: jakarta-ee, jaas, payara, jdbcrealm

I m triyng to deploy many Java EE Web application on the same payara domain. Each application have security constraints, for that i'm using JAAS.

I'm triyng to setup many jdbcRealms for each application, each one of them related to a jdbc connection pool to retrive user credentials from databases.

The first application(first defined jdbcRealm) work well, but the second one geve me the following error :

```
GRAVE:   jdbcrealm.invaliduser AVERTISSEMENT:   
WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException:Login failed: Security Exception
```

I don't find any error on my jdbcRealm definition, i'v only worried if i can define more than a one jdbcRealm per domain.

Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the user AVERTISSEMENT isn't found in the table that the second realm searches in. If you use different table of users for these 2 realms, you probably forgot to create on of the tables in the database or forgot to create the user in it.

Comment: First, thank s a lot for your reply, OndrejM. I can conclude from your answer that it is possible to define more than one JdbcRealm by domain what was my big question. I v verrified my realms definitions and it looks Ok everything good, every database carry the account and groups table definition, and the jdbc pool used form authentication are correctly setted. Will look further and try to report. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts I was able to create my jdbc realm for my deployed application on payara 5.182.
[image]
The tricks to make it work, is, to not set the *encryption algorithm* or the *encoding*.
Only the **Jdbc resource** name, the table for **accounts** and **groups** are enough.
[image]

I have tested the procedure many times on different OS and JVMs and it works.